# HeadlessException while launching Jasper iReport

Tags: swing, ubuntu, ireport

I am trying to run Jasper iReport on Ubuntu 10.04 and getting `java.awt.HeadlessException`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:173)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:437)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:419)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:384)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame.<init>(SwingUtilities.java:1758)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.getSharedOwnerFrame(SwingUtilities.java:1835)
    at javax.swing.JDialog.<init>(JDialog.java:270)
    at javax.swing.JDialog.<init>(JDialog.java:204)
    at it.businesslogic.ireport.gui.SplashDialog.<init>(SplashDialog.java:44)
    at it.businesslogic.ireport.gui.MainFrame.main(MainFrame.java:7826)
```

Please help me overcome this situation.

Comment: Right-click on your desktop, create a Launcher, add your iReport-n.n.n/bin/ireport and it should work if you click on it. Do not move your ireport shell script. I would update to 4.1.1.

Comment: It's not working in the system where I am getting the error. But it's working in another system where no error of java.awt.HeadlessException

Answer (score 0):

Install

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

accordingly.

The JRE packages seem to have limited graphics included??